# Androidでサブネットマスクを取得するには

Tags: android, java

UDPのブロードキャスト送信を行うアプリケーションを作りたくて、送信先として端末が所属しているネットワークのブロードキャストアドレスを指定しようと思っています。
例えば端末が`192.168.10.34`というアドレスを持っていてサブネットマスクが`255.255.255.0`であるとき、ブロードキャストアドレスとして`192.168.10.255`を指定すれば良いことはわかっているのですが、どうすればAndroidのJava APIを使って端末が所属しているネットワークのサブネットマスクが取得できるのかがわかりません。
何か良い方法はありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

サブネットマスクは[`InterfaceAddress#getNetworkPrefixLength()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InterfaceAddress.html#getNetworkPrefixLength())メソッドで取得できます。

```
try {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaceEnumeration =  NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while(networkInterfaceEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaceEnumeration.nextElement();
        for (InterfaceAddress interfaceAddress : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
            Log.i("debug", "ipAddress  : " + interfaceAddress.getAddress());
            Log.i("debug", "broadcast  : " + interfaceAddress.getBroadcast());
            Log.i("debug", "subnetMask : " + interfaceAddress.getNetworkPrefixLength());
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

例えばこのような結果が返ってきます。

> I/debug: ipAddress  : /192.168.1.2
>   I/debug: broadcast  : /192.168.1.255
>   I/debug: subnetMask : 24

結果が`short`で返ってきます。`24`という値はリファレンスを参照すると、IPv4の`255.255.255.0`であることが分かります。

`getBroadcast()`でブロードキャストアドレスも取れるので、直接こちらを指定した方が楽だと思います。